# How to insert enter() selections at locations corresponding to its data?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Let's say I bind a list of numbers to, say, 'li' elements using the numbers themselves as keys. So if I start with [1,2], then I get:

1

2

Now if I update that list to [1,3,2], then i want the HTML to look like:

1

3

2

I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this, since if I just do an enter().append('li'), then the enter selection is 3, so the HTML looks like:

1

2

3

(A selection also has insert(), but that takes only constant values and not a callback.)

Answer (score 2):

You need to do an update as well:

```
var container = d3.select("ul");
var selection = container.selectAll("li").data([1, 3, 2]);

// Enter
selection.enter().append("li");

// Update
selection.text(function(d) { return d; });
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that using selection.order after updating seems to work, but it's still not wholly satisfying since I wanted to do it while it was inserting.

Comment: Use selection.order. If you use a key function for your data-join, it also makes sure that your update selection is in the correct order.